# Create buffers from points by attribute

Tags: qgis, buffer, clustering

Suppose I have a points shapefile with a 'group' attribute, each value of which identifies a number of points (e.g. group=1 identifies points 1,3,6 and group=2 identifies points 2,4,5).

How can I create a buffer for each group that contains all the points belonging to that group?

Comment: It's classic Voronoi proximity polygons task. Create them first and dissolve using group name.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using this in the geometry generator in the layer properties.
(Change the Simple Fill into the geometry generator)

```
Case
when "group" = 1 then buffer($geometry,0.25)
when "group" = 2 then buffer($geometry,0.5)
else buffer($geometry,0)
End
```

This should create buffers depending on your group type.
Below you have a pictures of layer properties window to show you how to change to geometry generator, and the resulting buffers

[image: Properties of Layer Image]

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is **Buffer vectors** tool in (`Processing Toolbox | GDAL | Vector geoprocessing`), which has `Dissolve by attribute` option.